# Field names don't seem to carry over into a crosstab query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a chain of queries - that data goes from a table to a select query, then to a union query, then another select query, then finally to a crosstab.  Each query works at each step, until I get to the crosstab. At that point, I get an error that a field from the original table is required but not available.

Here's the query chain:

First select query, called **HSICInfantsSummary**

```
 SELECT 
      Dates.[Report type], Dates.Start, Dates.End, 
      HSICInfantsReport.CHILD_CONTACT_ID AS ID, 
      .....
   FROM ((HSICInfantsReport 
       INNER JOIN HSInterconceptionReport ON HSICInfantsReport.CHILD_CONTACT_ID = HSInterconceptionReport.CLIENTUNIQUEIDENTIFICATION)
       INNER JOIN HSDemographicsReport ON HSICInfantsReport.CHILD_CONTACT_ID = HSDemographicsReport.CONTACT_ID)
       INNER JOIN (Dates INNER JOIN [Active client list] ON Dates.[Report type] = [Active client list].[Report type]) ON HSICInfantsReport.CHILD_CONTACT_ID = [Active client list].ClientID;
```

This goes into a Union query called **Insurance Detail**:

```
select "Client" as type, CLIENTUNIQUEIDENTIFICATION as ID, Admin_Date, Insurance from HSInterconceptionReport 
union all select "Client", CONTACT_ID, admin_date, insurance from HSPPScreeningReport 
union all select "Client", CONTACT_ID, admin_date, insurance from HSPreconceptionReport 
union all select "Client", CLIENTUNIQUEIDENTIFICATION, AdminDate, HealthInsuranceTypesIDs from HSPrenatalScreeningReport
union all select "Infant", format(ID) & " - " & format(DOB) & " - " & birthorder, Admin_date, BabyInsurance  from HSICInfantsSummary 
UNION ALL select "Infant", format(ID) & " - " & format(DOB & " - " & birthorder), Admin_Date, BBYInsurance from HSPPInfantsSummary;
```

This goes into another select query called **Insurance Summary - client**:

```
SELECT  
  [All participants summary].[report type],
  [Insurance detail].type, 
  [Insurance detail].ID, 
  .....
FROM [Insurance detail] 
  INNER JOIN [All participants summary] ON [Insurance detail].ID = [All participants summary].ID
GROUP BY  
  [All participants summary].[report type],
  [Insurance detail].type, 
  [Insurance detail].ID, 
  ....
HAVING ((([Insurance detail].type)="Client") AND (([Insurance detail].Admin_Date)=(select max(admin_date) from [insurance detail] T where T.id=[insurance detail].id)))
ORDER BY [Insurance detail].ID, [All participants summary].EnrolledDate;
```

This query works fine and gives the expected results.  Then I want to do a crosstab of one data column:

```
TRANSFORM Count([Insurance summary - client].ID) AS CountOfID  
SELECT [Insurance summary - client].[report type]  
FROM [Insurance summary - client]  
GROUP BY [Insurance summary - client].[report type]  
PIVOT [Insurance summary - client].Insured;
```

And this is where it breaks.  This query should know the field "ID" from Insurance summarry - client, but it seems to want to go all they way back to the table that is the original source for the ID, and doesn't find what it needs.  The error message is:

[image]

Can you tell me why this happens, and more importantly how to work around it?

Comment: One workaround is always (though clumsy): INSERT the results of `Insurance Summary - client` into a temporary table (that you empty beforehand), and build the crosstab query based on that table. Since it's just a few lines of VBA, I would probably do this. It might even improve performance.

Comment: thanks - I've done that before to fix the same problem, but was hoping for a solution that didn't require that step.  I should have noted that in my question.